# How do I write a JavaScript function where a sound plays whenever any key is pressed but stop playing when the key is released

Tags: javascript

I wrote the code below to play a sound whenever a key is pressed

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', ()=> {engineSound.play();})
```

But when the code is executed, every other thing is frozen and the sound continues playing even though the key is no longer being pressed.

Comment: did my answer ended up helping you?

Comment: Yes, it did, thank you!

Comment: if so, could you please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `engineSound.stop()` method, and your code should look like this.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', ()=> {engineSound.play();})
window.addEventListener('keyup', ()=> {engineSound.stop();})
```